# В чем может быть проблема с отображением view

Tags: ios, xcode

Есть у меня кастомное вью которое я устанавливаю как background

Так вот все работало нормально, потом я обратил внимание, что оно немного сьехало...

Долно выглядеть вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вернулся на пару коммитов назад и там все в порядке, все отображается так как в `storyboard`

Не могу найти в чем может быть ошибка...

Answer (score 0):

Свяжите констрейнтами ваше кастомное вью и основное по всем 4м сторонам.
**Пример на objective c :**

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:self.view
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.customView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1.0
                                constant:0];

[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```